# POSIXct daylight saving issues (summertime)

Tags: r

I get the following reply when asking for seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00;

```
> as.numeric(as.POSIXct('1970-01-01'))
[1] -3600
```

I was hoping for a result of `0`. I'm guessing this is the response when asking while in in a daylight savings zone - summertime - such as myself (CEST).

I know there are some discussion regarding this,
I was just curious if it existed some nifty new package in R which could solve this without workarounds.

Big thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the timezone explicitly:

```
as.numeric(as.POSIXct('1970-01-01', tz = "GMT"))
## [1] 0
```

or set your entire session:

```
Sys.setenv(TZ = "GMT")
as.numeric(as.POSIXct('1970-01-01'))
## [1] 0
Sys.setenv(TZ = "")
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for reply.